# Opening a zip file that contains a csv file to use in a rake task

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, csv

I have a rake task that looks like this

```
require 'open-uri'
require 'csv'
namespace :Table do
   task reload: :environment do
       ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("TRUNCATE Table RESTART IDENTITY")
       csv_text = open('URL')
       csv = CSV.parse(csv_text, :headers=>true)
       csv.each do |row|
         Table.create(table columns)
       end
   end
end
```

Now i can either have the file come back as gzip or zip. It has to be compressed however the csv is the only file inside the zip file.

Any ideas how i can make this open the csv inside the zip file?

Thanks for the help

Sam

Comment: You'll need to unzip it somewhere, eg to a temp folder, and then read it.  There's various ways to do this, i usually just shell out to a command line zip tool.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ruby core includes Zlib support. If you've got a URL pointing to a gzipped file, you can use [Zlib::GzipReader](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.0/libdoc/zlib/rdoc/Zlib/GzipReader.html) to inflate the `Tempfile` returned by `open`.

```
gzipped = open('URL')
csv_text = Zlib::GzipReader.new(gzipped).read
csv = CSV.parse(csv_text, :headers=>true)
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use the [rubyzip](https://github.com/rubyzip/rubyzip) gem, read the file down to a temp file unzip it, pull the file you want and open it normally as a local file for the CSV.

```
require 'open-uri'
require 'csv'
require 'zip'
namespace :Table do
   task reload: :environment do
       ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("TRUNCATE Table RESTART IDENTITY")

       t=Tempfile.new("foo.zip")
       url = open("url")
       t.binmode
       t.write stringIo.read
       t.close

       zip_file = Zip::File.open(t.path)
       entry = zip_file.glob('*.csv').first

       csv_text = entry.get_input_stream.read
       csv = CSV.parse(csv_text, :headers=>true)
       csv.each do |row|
         Table.create(table columns)
       end
   end
end
```

Comment: ill attempt this shortly!

Comment: Hi there, Youve put `file.open /tmp/foo.zip` Is this the name fo the file to be opened? If i'm getting my file from the url `tickets.com/data/data.csv` how would i get this?

Comment: ok added this however i get this error, `LoadError: cannot load such file -- zip`

Comment: Ok ignore the last error! this is the new one, `NameError: undefined local variable or method `stringIo' for main:Object`

Comment: Probably should be `StringIO`

Comment: @MaxWilliams `NameError: uninitialized constant StringIo`